# how to use a handle in VB.net to access forms in another process?

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls, handle

I want to get a structured list of ALL processes on my Computer and all their Forms and and all their controls and so on - I am working with VB.net in Visual Studio 2017 - here is my code:

```
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        ' only processes with a MainWindow (=Applicatios)
        If p.MainWindowTitle > "" Then
            Debug.Print("Process: Name=" & p.ProcessName.ToString & " MainWindow=" & p.MainWindowTitle)

            ' get handle of MainWindow of this process
            Dim MWh As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle

            ' loop thru ChildWindows down from MainWindow
            ' I expect them to be forms and/or controls
            Dim CHh As IntPtr = New IntPtr(0)
            CHh = FindWindowEx(MWh, CHh, vbNullString, vbNullString)
            Do While Not CHh.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)

                Debug.WriteLine(". MainWindow: " & MWh.ToString())
                Debug.WriteLine(". Child: " & CHh.ToString())

                ' ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
                ' I have a handle to the child in CHh but I dont know how to use it to dig deeper
                ' - what Kind of Child is this?
                ' - what ist the Title/Name/Text?
                ' - access to sub-childs...
                ' ????????????????????????????????

                CHh = FindWindowEx(MWh, CHh, vbNullString, vbNullString)
            Loop
        End If
    Next
```

It loops through all applications and "downwards" through their children - I get the handle from each child - but I don't know how to use it to get more information about this child.
What kind of child is this?
What is the Title/Name/Text?
How can I get access to sub-children?

Comment: See some sample code here for enumerating windows. Note this won't list windowless controls. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html

Comment: You have [UIAutomation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview) for this. [TreeWalker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.treewalker) can be used to enumerate child elements in their hierarchy. For each element you can read, e.g., the [ControlType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.controltype) property, which tells you what kind of elements that is and also determine what *Patterns* are available (the element's *capabilities*). And so on.

Comment: *They got the main window from the Process.MainWindowHandle property. But that property is synthetic. Windows doesn’t have a formal concept of a “main window”; a program can create multiple top-level visible windows, and as far as Windows is concerned, they are all of equal importance.* https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180511-00/?p=98735. So you enumerate windows not process. IE Browsers are made up of multiple processes.

Comment: @KL-1: thank you, works as designed, also with children - BUT next questions:

Comment: which fields can i get besides WindowText or ClasName eg the type of the object

Comment: or how can know which functions USER32.dll is offering for this? and how to use them?

Comment: ClassName is the type of object. What information do you require?

Comment: eg when the control is a listbox, i want to have access to the content of this listbox - or Content of a Textbox ...

Comment: very helpful i think would be to understand how to learn which functions are in eg USER32.dll and how to use them

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettext

Comment: @Jimi, Thanks, you are right - but I will follow the "legacy way" for the Moment

Comment: Keep in mind that in UWP / WPF etc. applications, only the main Window has a Handle, all other child windows (what you'd call `Controls` in WinForms) don't, so you cannot enumerate anything using Handles.

Comment: @all: thanky you for the moment - I got consumed by other priorities - will follw  up in a few weeks